# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have web-rest Spring application. For the second entity I have 2 fields with LocalDate: arrivalTime, departureTime.
I realized CRUD methods. It's okey. But when I tried to search by date(since arrivalTime to departureTime) I have a mistake:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate';

I have correct answer for my rest module. I don't know what to do.
My entity:

```
   @NotNull(message = "arrival time is a required field")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate arrivalTime;

@NotNull(message = "departure time is a required field")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate departureTime;

public Resident() {
}

public Resident(String firstName, String lastName, String email, LocalDate arrivalTime, LocalDate departureTime, Integer apartmentNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    this.departureTime = departureTime;
    this.apartmentNumber = apartmentNumber;
}
```

My web controller

```
    @GetMapping("/search")
public String searchAllResidentByDate(@RequestParam(name = "arrivalTime", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate arrivalTime,
                                      @RequestParam(name = "departureTime", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate departureTime,
                                      Model model) {
    LOGGER.debug("search residents by date() {} {}", arrivalTime, departureTime);
    List<Resident> residentListByTime = residentService.findAllByTime(arrivalTime, departureTime);
    model.addAttribute("allResidentsAttribute", residentListByTime);
    return "Residents_list";
}
```

Service-rest:

```
    @Override
public List<Resident> findAllByTime(LocalDate arrivalTime, LocalDate departureTime) {
    String searchUrl = "http://localhost:8080/search";
    String arrivalTimeString = "{arrivalTime}";
    String departureTimeString = "{departureTime}";
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(searchUrl).queryParam("arrivalTime", arrivalTimeString)
            .queryParam("departureTime", departureTimeString);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<Apartment> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    return restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Resident>>() {
    }).getBody();
}
```

Rest controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<Resident>> searchAllResidentByDate(
        @RequestParam("arrivalTime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate arrivalTime,
        @RequestParam("departureTime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate departureTime) {
    List<Resident> residents = residentService.findAllByTime(arrivalTime, departureTime);
    LOGGER.debug("Find residents by date, where arrivalTime = {} and end departureTime => {} In the amount of {} ", arrivalTime, departureTime, residents.size());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(residents, HttpStatus.FOUND);
}
```

I've got a correct result for rest by this URL:

> http://localhost:8090/search?arrivalTime=2021-03-01&departureTime=2021-04-04

Html part:

```
    <form class="d-flex"
      action="/search"
      th:method="@{get}">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="arrivalTime" type="date" aria-label="arrivalTime"
               id="arrivalTime">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="departureTime" type="date" aria-label="departureTime"
               id="departureTime">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Search</button>
</form>
```

When I click on Seach button, I have this URL:

> http://localhost:8080/search?arrivalTime=2021-03-01&departureTime=2021-05-09
> I need this pattern:yyyy-MM-dd. But something doesn't work.

My POM for web-module:

> 

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.punko</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.punko</groupId>
        <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.punko</groupId>
        <artifactId>service-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.punko.web_app.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: That pattern is the default (you don't need to specify it, and if you're using a Jackson annotation, they don't apply to Spring conversions). Post your POM or `build.gradle`; it looks like a dependency problem, because this normally works out of the box.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-, I added Pom.xml

Comment: I find a mistake. Instead " String arrivalTimeString = "{arrivalTime}";" I use String arrivalTimeString = arrivalTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));  And put it in buider. But now nothing happen, when I click on search. Only loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used incorrect port. I needed 8090, instead 8080. Thank you

Comment: You should accept your answer.